# Automation UI - Custom Controls Won't Show Up

Tags: c#, automation

I have an issue with automating UI.
I have a code that works, but is hard to debug - So I created one that should be much more comfortable, but in one case, it will not work - That case being a custom control.

I can't figure out why one code works, while the other won't!
I tried many ways and searched the web (many similar stuff, but not good enough for me)

This is the code that works:

```
    class ElementUtils
{

    public ElementUtils()
    {

    }

    public AutomationElement FindObjectFullPath(string parent, string childElements, string controlType)
    {
        string[] strElements = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childElements))
        {
            childElements = childElements.Trim();

            strElements = childElements.Split(new string[] { "[", "]" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent) && !(childElements.StartsWith("[") && childElements.EndsWith("]")))
                throw new Exception("parent element and child elements are all empty. this input cannot be processed!");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent))
                parent = strElements[0];

        }

        AutomationElement e = null;

        AutomationElementCollection desktop = GetDesktopElements();
        e = FindElement(desktop, parent);
        if (e == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        AutomationElement ae = e;
        if (strElements != null) // ignore parent if you have full path element format
            ae = LocateElement(strElements, e, controlType);

        if (ae != null)
        {
            string fullPath = BuildElementFullNameForTest(ae);
            return ae;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private AutomationElement LocateElement(string[] elements, AutomationElement ae, string controlType)
    {
        AutomationElement e = ae;
        List<AutomationElement> eList = new List<AutomationElement>();
        List<AutomationElement> newElemList = new List<AutomationElement>();
        eList.Add(e);

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
        {
            if (elements[i] == "null")
                continue;

            if (elements[i] == "empty")
                elements[i] = "";

            newElemList.Clear();
            newElemList.AddRange(eList);
            eList.Clear();

            foreach (AutomationElement ee in newElemList)
            {
                AutomationElementCollection c = GetObjectElements(ee);

                bool exactMatch = false;

                if (elements[i].StartsWith("#") && elements[i].EndsWith("#"))
                {
                    elements[i] = elements[i].Substring(1, elements[i].Length - 2);
                    exactMatch = true;
                }

                if (i == elements.Length - 1 && !controlType.Equals("IGNORE") && !controlType.Equals(""))
                {
                    eList.AddRange(FindAllSubElements(c, elements[i], StringToControlType(controlType), exactMatch));
                }
                else
                {
                    eList.AddRange(FindAllSubElements(c, elements[i], null, exactMatch));
                }
            }
        }

        if (eList.Count == 0)
            return null;
        return eList[0];
    }

    private List<AutomationElement> FindAllSubElements(AutomationElementCollection c, string ae, ControlType controlType, bool exactMatch)
    {
        List<AutomationElement> eList = new List<AutomationElement>();

        bool found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < c.Count; i++)
        {
            // name should be exactly as expected element name
            if (exactMatch)
            {
                if (c[i].Current.Name.Equals(ae))
                    found = true;
            }
            else if (c[i].Current.Name.Contains(ae)) // name should be contained in expected element name
            {
                found = true;
            }

            if (found)
            {
                found = false;
                if (controlType != null)
                {
                    if (c[i].Current.ControlType.CompareTo(controlType) == 0)
                    {
                        eList.Add(c[i]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    eList.Add(c[i]);
                }
            }

        }
        return eList;
    }

    public AutomationElementCollection GetDesktopElements()
    {
        return AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
    }

    public AutomationElementCollection GetObjectElements(AutomationElement e)
    {
        return e.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
    }

    private AutomationElement FindElement(AutomationElementCollection c, string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Count; i++)
        {
            if (c[i].Current.Name.Contains(name))
            {
                return c[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private AutomationElement FindElement(AutomationElementCollection c, string name, ControlType controlType)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Count; i++)
        {
            if (c[i].Current.Name.Contains(name) && c[i].Current.ControlType.CompareTo(controlType) == 0)
                return c[i];
        }
        return null;
    }

    private AutomationElement FindElement(List<AutomationElement> elements, string name)
    {
        foreach (AutomationElement e in elements)
        {
            if (e.Current.Name.Contains(name))
                return e;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private string BuildElementFullNameForTest(AutomationElement element)
    {
        TreeWalker walker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
        AutomationElement elementParent;
        AutomationElement node = element;

        if (element == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string elementFullName = element.Current.Name + "]";

        do
        {
            elementParent = walker.GetParent(node);
            if (elementParent == AutomationElement.RootElement)
                break;
            if (!elementParent.Current.Name.Equals(""))
                elementFullName = elementParent.Current.Name + "][" + elementFullName;
            node = elementParent;
        }
        while (true);

        return "[" + elementFullName;
    }

    private void WalkAllElements(AutomationElement rootElement, List<AutomationElement> collection)
    {
        TreeWalker walker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
        AutomationElement e = walker.GetFirstChild(rootElement);
        while (e != null)
        {
            collection.Add(e);
            WalkAllElements(e, collection);
            e = walker.GetNextSibling(e);
        }
    }


    private ControlType StringToControlType(string controlType)
    {
        switch (controlType)
        {
            case "Button":
                return ControlType.Button;
            case "Calendar":
                return ControlType.Calendar;
            case "CheckBox":
                return ControlType.CheckBox;
            case "ComboBox":
                return ControlType.ComboBox;
            case "DataGrid":
                return ControlType.DataGrid;
            case "DataItem":
                return ControlType.DataItem;
            case "Document":
                return ControlType.Document;
            case "Edit":
                return ControlType.Edit;
            case "Group":
                return ControlType.Group;
            case "Header":
                return ControlType.Header;
            case "HeaderItem":
                return ControlType.HeaderItem;
            case "Hyperlink":
                return ControlType.Hyperlink;
            case "Image":
                return ControlType.Image;
            case "List":
                return ControlType.List;
            case "ListItem":
                return ControlType.ListItem;
            case "Menu":
                return ControlType.Menu;
            case "MenuBar":
                return ControlType.MenuBar;
            case "MenuItem":
                return ControlType.MenuItem;
            case "Pane":
                return ControlType.Pane;
            case "ProgressBar":
                return ControlType.ProgressBar;
            case "RadioButton":
                return ControlType.RadioButton;
            case "ScrollBar":
                return ControlType.ScrollBar;
            case "Separator":
                return ControlType.Separator;
            case "Slider":
                return ControlType.Slider;
            case "Spinner":
                return ControlType.Spinner;
            case "SplitButton":
                return ControlType.SplitButton;
            case "StatusBar":
                return ControlType.StatusBar;
            case "Tab":
                return ControlType.Tab;
            case "TabItem":
                return ControlType.TabItem;
            case "Table":
                return ControlType.Table;
            case "Text":
                return ControlType.Text;
            case "Thumb":
                return ControlType.Thumb;
            case "TitleBar":
                return ControlType.TitleBar;
            case "ToolBar":
                return ControlType.ToolBar;
            case "ToolTip":
                return ControlType.ToolTip;
            case "Tree":
                return ControlType.Tree;
            case "TreeItem":
                return ControlType.TreeItem;
            case "Window":
                return ControlType.Window;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

This is the code that won't:

```
    class ElementUtils
{
    static TestLog tl;
    static TestLog ofl = new TestLog("ObjectFinderLog.txt", true);

    public ElementUtils(TestLog testLog)
    {
        tl = testLog;
    }

    private ControlType StringToControlType(string controlType)
    {
        switch (controlType)
        {
            case "Button":
                return ControlType.Button;
            case "Calendar":
                return ControlType.Calendar;
            case "CheckBox":
                return ControlType.CheckBox;
            case "ComboBox":
                return ControlType.ComboBox;
            case "DataGrid":
                return ControlType.DataGrid;
            case "DataItem":
                return ControlType.DataItem;
            case "Document":
                return ControlType.Document;
            case "Edit":
                return ControlType.Edit;
            case "Group":
                return ControlType.Group;
            case "Header":
                return ControlType.Header;
            case "HeaderItem":
                return ControlType.HeaderItem;
            case "Hyperlink":
                return ControlType.Hyperlink;
            case "Image":
                return ControlType.Image;
            case "List":
                return ControlType.List;
            case "ListItem":
                return ControlType.ListItem;
            case "Menu":
                return ControlType.Menu;
            case "MenuBar":
                return ControlType.MenuBar;
            case "MenuItem":
                return ControlType.MenuItem;
            case "Pane":
                return ControlType.Pane;
            case "ProgressBar":
                return ControlType.ProgressBar;
            case "RadioButton":
                return ControlType.RadioButton;
            case "ScrollBar":
                return ControlType.ScrollBar;
            case "Separator":
                return ControlType.Separator;
            case "Slider":
                return ControlType.Slider;
            case "Spinner":
                return ControlType.Spinner;
            case "SplitButton":
                return ControlType.SplitButton;
            case "StatusBar":
                return ControlType.StatusBar;
            case "Tab":
                return ControlType.Tab;
            case "TabItem":
                return ControlType.TabItem;
            case "Table":
                return ControlType.Table;
            case "Text":
                return ControlType.Text;
            case "Thumb":
                return ControlType.Thumb;
            case "TitleBar":
                return ControlType.TitleBar;
            case "ToolBar":
                return ControlType.ToolBar;
            case "ToolTip":
                return ControlType.ToolTip;
            case "Tree":
                return ControlType.Tree;
            case "TreeItem":
                return ControlType.TreeItem;
            case "Window":
                return ControlType.Window;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public AutomationElement FindObjectFullPath(string parent, string childElements, string controlType)
    {
        string[] strElements = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childElements))
        {
            childElements = childElements.Trim();
            strElements = childElements.Split(new string[] { "[", "]" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent) && !(childElements.StartsWith("[") && childElements.EndsWith("]")))
            {
                throw new Exception("parent element and child elements are all empty. this input cannot be processed!");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent))
                parent = strElements[0];

        }

        AutomationElement parentAutomationElement = null;
        AutomationElementCollection desktop = GetDesktopElements();
        parentAutomationElement = FindElement(desktop, parent);
        if (parentAutomationElement == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //Generate object list
        ObjectFinderElement root = new ObjectFinderElement(parentAutomationElement, ofl);
        root.PrintToLog("\n\nLog for object path " + childElements);
        root.PrintToLog("\n" + root.PrintTree());

        return LocateElement(strElements, root, controlType);
    }

    public AutomationElementCollection GetDesktopElements()
    {
        return AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
    }

    private AutomationElement FindElement(AutomationElementCollection c, string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Count; i++)
        {
            if (c[i].Current.Name.Contains(name))
            {
                return c[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private AutomationElement LocateElement(string[] elements, ObjectFinderElement root, string controlType)
    {
        ObjectFinderElement objectPath = root;
        String foundPath = "";
        if (elements == null)
            return objectPath.GetAutomationElement();

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
        {
            if (elements[i] == "null")
                continue;

            if (elements[i] == "empty")
                elements[i] = "";

            foundPath += "[" + elements[i] + "]";
            Boolean exactMatch = false;

            if (elements[i].StartsWith("#") && elements[i].EndsWith("#"))
            {
                elements[i] = elements[i].Substring(1, elements[i].Length - 2);
                exactMatch = true;
            }

            ControlType ct = null;

            if (i == elements.Length - 1 && !controlType.Equals("IGNORE") && !controlType.Equals(""))
            {
                ct = StringToControlType(controlType);
            }

            objectPath = objectPath.FindObjectFinderElement(elements[i], exactMatch, ct);

            if (objectPath == null)
            {
                tl.AddLine("Error: FindObjectFullPath - Object path '" + foundPath + "' could not be found");
                return null;
            }
        }

        tl.AddLine("Success: FindObjectFullPath: Object path " + foundPath + " was found successfully!");
        return objectPath.GetAutomationElement();
    }

}

class ObjectFinderElement
{
    private AutomationElement current;
    private List<ObjectFinderElement> children = new List<ObjectFinderElement>();
    private static TestLog ofl;

    public ObjectFinderElement(AutomationElement current, TestLog testlog)
    {
        ofl = testlog;
        this.current = current;
        AutomationElementCollection childrenTemp = current.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
        children.Capacity = childrenTemp.Count;
        foreach (AutomationElement child in childrenTemp)
            children.Add(new ObjectFinderElement(child, ofl));
    }

    public String PrintTree()
    {
        return PrintTree("");
    }

    public String PrintTree(String preText)
    {
        String self = preText + GetExtendedInfo();

        foreach (ObjectFinderElement child in children)
            self += "\n" + child.PrintTree("   |" + preText);

        return self;
    }

    public ObjectFinderElement FindObjectFinderElement(String name)
    {
        return FindObjectFinderElement(name, false, null);
    }

    public ObjectFinderElement FindObjectFinderElement(String name, Boolean exactMatch)
    {
        return FindObjectFinderElement(name, exactMatch, null);
    }

    public ObjectFinderElement FindObjectFinderElement(String name, Boolean exactMatch, ControlType controlType)
    {
        String ct = "IGNORE";
        if (controlType != null)
            ct = controlType.LocalizedControlType.ToString();

        ofl.AddLine("Scanning for \"" + name + "\" - Exact Match: " + exactMatch + " Control Type: " + ct);

        ObjectFinderElement res = FindObjectFinderElementIMP(name, exactMatch, controlType);
        if (res != null)
        {
            ofl.AddLine("Found element \"" + res.GetName() + "\"");
        }
        return res;
    }

    public ObjectFinderElement FindObjectFinderElementIMP(String name, Boolean exactMatch, ControlType controlType)
    {
        ObjectFinderElement res = null;
        ofl.AddLine("Scanning element \"" + current.Current.Name + "\"");
        Boolean found = CompareElements(name, exactMatch, controlType);

        if (found)
            res = this;
        else
        {
            foreach (ObjectFinderElement child in children)
            {
                res = child;
                if (res.CompareElements(name, exactMatch, controlType))
                    return res;
            }
            foreach (ObjectFinderElement child in children)
            {
                res = child.FindObjectFinderElementIMP(name, exactMatch, controlType);
                if (res != null)
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (found)
            return res;
        return null;
    }

    private Boolean CompareElements(String name, Boolean exactMatch, ControlType controlType)
    {
        Boolean found = false;
        // name should be exactly as expected element name
        if (exactMatch)
        {
            if (current.Current.Name.Equals(name))
                found = true;
        }
        //name should be contained in expected element name
        else if (current.Current.Name.Contains(name))
        {
            found = true;
        }
        //Test for control type, if needed
        if (found == true && controlType != null)
        {
            if (current.Current.ControlType.CompareTo(controlType) != 0)
                found = false;
        }

        return found;
    }

    public AutomationElement GetAutomationElement()
    {
        return current;
    }

    public String GetName()
    {
        return current.Current.Name;
    }

    public String GetExtendedInfo()
    {
        return "\"" + current.Current.Name + "\" - " + current.Current.ControlType.LocalizedControlType + " - " + children.Count + " Children";
    }

    public String GetFullInfo()
    {
        return "Name: \"" + current.Current.Name + "\" - Localized Control Type: " + current.Current.ControlType.LocalizedControlType + " - Bounding Rectangle: " + current.Current.BoundingRectangle + " - Is Content Element: " + current.Current.IsContentElement + " - Is Control Element: " + current.Current.IsControlElement + " - Is Enabled: " + current.Current.IsEnabled + " - Is Keyboard Focusable: " + current.Current.IsKeyboardFocusable + " - Is Offscreen: " + current.Current.IsOffscreen;
    }

    public void PrintToLog(String text)
    {
        ofl.AddLine(text);
    }
}
```

I tried changing to tree walker (raw) as one has suggested over here. Did not work.
I also tried to change the ObjectFinderElement (bad name, I know, WIP - it had a different objective at first - to print the tree of the found elements only) to search for descendants rather than children, or even the entire subtree, but it does not work.

I'll try to make things clearer by explaining what I was trying to do.
In Outlook 2010, there is the left side-bar with the folder names. I want to reach it.
The full path (Using Inspect) is as follows: 
[Microsoft Outlook][NUIDocumentWindow][empty string][empty string][empty string][Folder List][outlook e-mail address][Inbox]

Now the issue, as I find it so far, is that the 2nd "empty string] is of type "Custom Control" - And when I print the element tree - it won't be there, and same goes for it's own children (which I need).

However, using the other method (first code segment) it seems to find - even though I can't print the tree, it does send the mouse to click it (the code segments do not include the actual automation).

From that, I concluded where the issue shows up - the element search. 
In the first code segment it is as followed:

```
public AutomationElementCollection GetObjectElements(AutomationElement e)
    {
        return e.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
    }
```

While in the 2nd code segment, the code for the population of the element tree is;

```
public ObjectFinderElement(AutomationElement current, TestLog testlog)
    {
        ofl = testlog;
        this.current = current;
        AutomationElementCollection childrenTemp = current.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
        children.Capacity = childrenTemp.Count;
        foreach (AutomationElement child in childrenTemp)
            children.Add(new ObjectFinderElement(child, ofl));
    }
```

So I assume it's the treescope. But even if (for testing purposes) I changed the scope to Subtree (having the list go crazy and with multiple elements) - the missing elements still won't be there!

I'll post the tree I received below (with treescope = Children, of course):

```
2/10/2014 11:55:55 AM - 

Log for object path [Folder List][Contacts]
2/10/2014 11:55:55 AM - 
"Inbox - test320@****.com - Microsoft Outlook" - window - 11 Children
   |"Frame Splitter" - pane - 0 Children
   |"Frame Splitter" - pane - 0 Children
   |"MsoDockTop" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |"Ribbon" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |"Ribbon" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |"MsoDockBottom" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |"Status Bar" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |"Status Bar" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |"FolderBar" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |"NUIDocumentWindow" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |"" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |"NUIDocumentWindow" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |"NUIDocumentWindow" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |"" - pane - 2 Children
   |   |"" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |"" - pane - 13 Children
   |   |   |   |"DAL=on" - tool bar - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"" - text - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"TestAppointment" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"Required: " - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"When:" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"Saturday, June 04, 2016 8:00 AM-8:30 AM" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"Location:" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"None" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 2 Children
   |   |   |   |   |"Vertical" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |   |"Day View" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 2 Children
   |   |   |   |   |   |"Message" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |   |   |   |"Vertical" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |"Microsoft Outlook Social Connector" - pane - 2 Children
   |   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |   |   |"Click to expand the People Pane" - button - 0 Children
   |"Table View" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |"Vertical" - pane - 1 Children
   |   |   |"" - pane - 0 Children
   |"Inbox - test320@****.com - Microsoft Outlook" - title bar - 4 Children
   |   |"System Menu Bar" - menu bar - 1 Children
   |   |   |"System" - menu item - 0 Children
   |   |"Minimize" - button - 0 Children
   |   |"Restore" - button - 0 Children
   |   |"Close" - button - 0 Children
```

This is a lot to read I suppose, but help would be much appreciated.

Update:
I have found one other hint - It seems that in order to find all of the elements, I need to use "AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);"

So I can't organize it like a tree! This is quite bothersome...

PS. I am having a hard time posting text as code...

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. I am not sure how, I was going to give up on it for the time being, so I had one quick rewrite from scratch. 3-4 minutes later and it works.

Here's the code for those interested;

```
using AutomationUtils;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Automation;

namespace GenericUIAutomation
{
class ElementTree
{
    private AutomationElement current;
    private List<ElementTree> children = new List<ElementTree>();
    private List<String> ancestorNames = new List<String>();
    private static TestLog ofl;

    public ElementTree(TestLog testlog)
    {
        ofl = testlog;
        this.current = AutomationElement.RootElement;
        //This is the root element, no ancestors.
        ancestorNames = null;
        AutomationElementCollection childrenTemp = current.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
        children.Capacity = childrenTemp.Count;

        List<String> childrenAncestors = new List<String>();
        childrenAncestors.Add(this.current.Current.Name);

        foreach (AutomationElement child in childrenTemp)
            children.Add(new ElementTree(child, childrenAncestors));

        childrenTemp = null;
    }

    public ElementTree(AutomationElement current, List<String> ancestorList)
    {
        this.current = current;
        this.ancestorNames = ancestorList;
        AutomationElementCollection childrenTemp = current.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
        children.Capacity = childrenTemp.Count;

        List<String> childrenAncestors = new List<String>();
        childrenAncestors.AddRange(ancestorList);
        childrenAncestors.Add(this.current.Current.Name);

        foreach (AutomationElement child in childrenTemp)
            children.Add(new ElementTree(child, childrenAncestors));

        childrenTemp = null;
    }

    public ElementTree FindInTree(String name, ControlType controlType, String[] ancestorList)
    {
        String ct = "IGNORE";
        if (controlType != null)
            ct = controlType.LocalizedControlType.ToString();

        ofl.AddLine("Scanning for \"" + name + "\" - " + " Control Type: " + ct);

        ElementTree res = FindInTreeIMP(name, controlType, ancestorList);
        if (res != null)
            ofl.AddLine("Success! Found element \"" + res.GetName() + "\" - " + res.GetAutomationElement().Current.ControlType.LocalizedControlType);
        else
            ofl.AddLine("Error! No matching element found.");
        return res;
    }

    public ElementTree FindInTreeIMP(String name, ControlType controlType, String[] ancestorList)
    {
        ofl.AddLine("Scanning element \"" + current.Current.Name + "\" - " + current.Current.ControlType.LocalizedControlType);
        Boolean found = CompareElements(name, controlType, ancestorList);

        if (found)
            return this;

        foreach (ElementTree child in children)
        {
            ElementTree res = child.FindInTreeIMP(name, controlType, ancestorList);
            if (res != null)
                return res;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private Boolean CompareElements(String name, ControlType controlType, String[] ancestorList)
    {
        Boolean found = false;

        //name should be contained in expected element name
        if (this.current.Current.Name.Contains(name))
        {
            PrintToLog("Name match found");
            found = true;
        }
        //Test for control type, if needed
        if (found == true && controlType != null)
        {
            PrintToLog("Control Type match found");
            if (this.current.Current.ControlType.CompareTo(controlType) != 0)
                found = false;
        }
        if (found == true && this.ancestorNames.Count >= ancestorList.Length)
        {
            PrintToLog("Searching for Ancestors");
            found = CheckAncestors(ancestorList);
        }
        else
            found = false;

        return found;
    }

    private Boolean CheckAncestors(String[] ancestorList)
    {
        Boolean found = false;
        foreach (String ancestorName in ancestorList)
        {
            PrintToLog("Scanning for ancestor " + ancestorName);
            foreach (String ancestorListElement in ancestorList)
                if (ancestorListElement.Contains(ancestorName))
                {
                    PrintToLog("Found ancestor " + ancestorListElement);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            if (found != true)
                return found;
            else
                continue;

        }
        return found;
    }

    public String PrintTree()
    {
        return "\n" + PrintTree("");
    }

    public String PrintTree(String preText)
    {
        String self = preText + GetExtendedInfo();

        foreach (ElementTree child in children)
            self += "\n" + preText + child.PrintTree(preText + "   |");
        return self;
    }

    public AutomationElement GetAutomationElement()
    {
        return current;
    }

    public String GetName()
    {
        return current.Current.Name;
    }

    public String GetExtendedInfo()
    {
        int childrenCount = 0;
        int ancestorsCount = 0;
        String name = current.Current.Name;
        String controlType = current.Current.ControlType.LocalizedControlType;

        if (children != null)
            childrenCount = children.Count;
        if (ancestorNames != null)
            ancestorsCount = ancestorNames.Count;

        return "\"" + name + "\" - " + controlType + " - " + childrenCount + " Children" + " - " + ancestorsCount + " Ancestors";
    }

    public void PrintToLog(String text)
    {
        ofl.AddLine(text);
    }
}
}
```

There is work to be done but... It works.